# Latex table pagebreak doest work

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

my girlfriend is trying to write her thesis in latex and she came up with following issue:

We are trying to enable a table to be split up among multiple pages (if needed) 
here is what i thought should work .... but it doesnt...

```html
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{8cm}

\begin{table}[h] 
\centering
\vspace*{1cm}
\caption{Überschrift} 
\begin{longtable}{ccc} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule 
 Name & nucleotide & verwendung \\
\midrule 
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If i compile this it will put table on the second page instead of splitting it up .....
im no latex native so please help me :-)

Answer (score 2):

A single `table` environment cannot be broken across pages. Here, I merely remove the `table` and `tabular` environments, and move the `\caption` inside the `longtable`, followed by a `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{8cm}

\centering
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{longtable}{ccc} 
\caption{Überschrift}\\ 
\toprule 
 Name & nucleotide & verwendung \\
\midrule 
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
test & aaaggg& klonierung\\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]